# Making my server to visible online

Tags: apache-http-server, wamp, easyphp

First I had installed [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com), and I was able to access my pages from other computers in my router network, as well as the virtual device used to debug Android programs (the purpose of my having a server).

This functionality failed, however, at some point over these past few days. While my own browser displays the pages just fine, other computers, my Android phone (on our room's WiFi), and my virtual device are no longer able to connect to my pages. I had not made any changes in the settings.

I uninstalled WAMP and installed EasyPHP. However, the problem was not resolved. I know this is rather vague, but does anyone here have an idea of what may have happened? I forwarded both port 80 (I know its the default HTTP port, I did it just to be safe), and now port 8888 which EasyPHP uses. I turned my firewall on my hosting computer off for good measure. I cannot access my pages from neither remote computers nor computers connected to my router. Any ideas you may have on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

As you're in a home network, you are very likely using DHCP for setting network addresses on your devices. Confirm that your IP has not changed by running:

```
ipconfig
```

Comment: It did change on me, oddly enough. Went from 13 to 19. Thank you!